Square head gas valve open or closed
I have a yellow 3/4" square head gas valve. it's in a tight location, how do I tell if it's open or closed? In the photo there are notches on top and are lined up with the gas line, does this mean it is open? See Photo of gas valve.


Yes, the notches stand in for conventional levers. Inline with the pipe or tubing indicates the open state.

You test the position of a valve by trying to close it (righty tighty lefty loosey except for a few exceptions).  If it moves, it was open.  If it does not, it was closed.  If you can't reach it, you need an extension.
Now that I see the photo, I'm pretty sure that valve has an extension on the back side we can't see, it looks too much like a typical gas valve.  Google result for yellow gas valve.

problem is I just can't access it very well, is there not a way to tell if open or closed?

Can you get to the termination point, Stove, grill hot water tank and see if there is a flame present?  Or smell gas?

@LarryMichaud "I just can't access it very well" This is a more serious problem. Gas valves exist to be accessed easily, so they can be turned off easily. Your gas plumbing has a bigger problem than which way this valve handle is pointing. The valve needs to be moved to a more accessible location. Then it can be replaced with an easier-to-identify-on-off kind of valve.
